# Some PVC are not deleted after helm purge

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openstack, persistent-volumes

In my statefulset I defined volumeClaimTemplates. Added definition of storageclass. After deployment I have PVC, PV and SC created. Reclaim policy is Delete.
However after performing helm delete <> --purge all resources are deleted except PVC's

I use kubernetes.io/cinder for dynamic provisioning.

Below pvc

```
NAME                            STATUS    VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS          AGE
data-x-kafka-0                  Bound     pvc-db37bd17-fe35-11ea-8161-fa163efa0a08   16Gi       RWO            sc-name               7m
```

Below pv

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS    CLAIM                               STORAGECLASS          REASON    AGE
pvc-db37bd17-fe35-11ea-8161-fa163efa0a08   16Gi       RWO            Delete           Bound     ns/data-x-kafka-0                   sc-name                         12m
```

Could you please give me direction, where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3313 this is working as intended because the PVCs got created by the statefulset and not helm itself.

Comment: I think it is correct on helm's part to leave the pvc untouched. 
But these orphan PVCs should be purged. Isnt that the desired behaviour? 
May be k8s controller should take care of this.

Comment: there is an alpha feature in K8s 1.23 to take care of this: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/12/16/kubernetes-1-23-statefulset-pvc-auto-deletion/